# JQuery não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: html, jquery

Fala galera! Tudo tranquilo?

Então, estou tendo alguns problemas com o funcionamento do JQuery. Estou tentando simplesmente aplicar algumas animações e transições ao meu site, como toggle(), fadeIn() e etc, porém várias delas ou não funcionam, ou funcionam parcialmente.

Por exemplo - enquanto funções como hide() e show() funcionam, fadeIn() e slideToggle() não funcionam. A função toggle(), por sua vez funciona, porém quando passo o parâmetro de velocidade de animação por ela, ele não muda nada.

O que estou suspeitando é que, por eu ter usado o template do Bootstrap, o CDN do JQuery que vem no fim do body com ele está dando algum conflito com o CDN que eu coloquei no head do documento. Porém, já tentei de tudo e nada faz ele funcionar.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

**HEAD DO DOCUMENTO**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>PEC</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#historia").hide();
            $("#metodologia").hide();
            $("#material").hide();
            $("#eventos").hide();

            $('#btn-historia').click(function() {
                $("#historia").toggle(6000);
            });

            $('#btn-metodologia').click(function() {
                $("#metodologia").toggle(6000);
            });

            $('#btn-material').click(function() {
                $("#material").toggle(6000);
            });

            $('#btn-eventos').click(function() {
                $("#eventos").toggle(6000);
            });
        });

    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



    <!--FONTS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krub" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
```

**FINAL DO BODY DO DOCUMENTO**

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc está usando a versão `slim` do jQuery

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js`

A Versão Slim, não tem vários recursos de animação, `ajax` e outros detalhes, por ser uma versão reduzida das funcionalidades do jQuery padrão.

> Sometimes you don’t need `ajax`, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone libraries that focus on `ajax` requests. And often it is simpler to use a combination of `CSS` and class manipulation for all your web `animations`. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the `ajax` and effects modules, **we’ve released a “slim” version that excludes these modules.**

Traduzindo: *"Às vezes, você não precisa de `ajax` ou prefere usar uma das muitas bibliotecas independentes que se concentram em solicitações de `ajax`. E muitas vezes é mais simples usar uma combinação de `CSS` e manipulação de classe para todas as suas **animações** da web. Juntamente com a versão regular do jQuery, que inclui os módulos `ajax` e efeitos, l**ançamos uma versão "slim" que exclui esses módulos.**"*

Fonte oficial: https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/20/jquery-3-3-1-fixed-dependencies-in-release-tag/

Minha dica é vc deixas apenas uma versão, a versão padrão completa, ao final do seu documento no lugar da `slim`, e tira o jquery do `head`

Comment: CARA me salvou aqui! Funcionou!

Porém uma coisa: como o JQuery está no fim do documento, eu devo linkar o meu arquivo externo de js após ele ou no head mesmo?

Comment: @LucasMendesGabriel legal jovem que bom que resolveu ai, evite importat mais de uma biblioteca jQuery, a não ser que seja o jQuery+jQueryUI por exemplo... Mas importar duas versões diferentes do mesmo jQuery não é indicado...

Comment: cara, muito obrigado mesmo, me ajudou demais! Vou me atentar nesse detalhe! Sigo com essa dúvida - quando coloco o JQuery no documento, devo então linkar meu arquivo externo de js após o JQuery, no fim do body?

Comment: @LucasMendesGabriel Exato meu caro! Qualquer arquivo .js que use as dependências do jQuery devi vir após ele no documento. A ordem padrão do próprio Bootstrap primeiro é o jQuery após ele o Popper e depois o Bootstrap.js, o quarto da lista seria o seu Custom.js com seus scripts. Se vc ainda for usar alguma outra biblioteca tipo OwlCarousel ou algo do tipo ela tb deve vir apos o jQuery, mas antes do seu Custom.js []´s

Comment: Hugo, nem sei como agradecer, amigo! De verdade, quebrei a cabeça com isso! Muitíssimo obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @LucasMendesGabriel sem problemas, eu tb já apanhei com isso rss, sou designer, não sou dev. então o js vive me pregando peça rss. Sucesso com o projeto!

Comment: Putz cara, eu sou estudante de web dev e to pengando uns freelas pra fazer. Então eu to apanhando direto aqui! hahahaha

Comment: @LucasMendesGabriel vc vai aprender mais fazendo freela do que na 
Facul :D. Brincadeiras a parto o StackOverflow está ai pra isso, para ajudar com questões técnicas mesmo. Aqui tem muita gente fere, basta caprichar na pergunta que sempre tem alguém para responder. 